# How do I verify a three variable identity?

Tags: trigonometry

I am confused on how to verify an identity with three variables.

Problem:  $$\cos(x+y+z) = \cos(x) \cos(y) \cos(z)$$

Where do I start?
Thanks

Comment: Take $x=0,y=\pi/2,z=\pi/2$ and you find $0=-1$. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $z= -y$, this would give $\cos(x) = \cos(x) \cos(y)^2$.

Setting $x=0$ would give $1 = \cos(y)^2$. Can this be true for all $y$?